# How can i export nested gridview data to word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two grid, one with auto-generated fields and the other not. how can i export two of the grid (which is actually together to one?) The following code illustrate how i bind two grid together using methods and a early image of the grid.

my code:

```
protected void BindHistoryReport()
{
    ArrayList listofavgrating = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList listofdouble = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList listofquestion = dbmanager.GetAllQuestion();
    ArrayList listofstaff = dbmanager.GetAllStaffDetails();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (staffinfo stf in listofstaff)
    {
        ArrayList listofhistorydates = dbmanager.GetTotalHistoryDates(stf.Uid);
        if (count==0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Section", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Function", typeof(string)));
            count++;
        }

        if (listofhistorydates.Count != 0 && listofquestion.Count != 0 && count > 0)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["UserID"] = stf.Uid;
            dr["Name"] = stf.Name;
            dr["Section"] = stf.Section;
            dr["Function"] = stf.Function;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        ViewState["HistoryGrid"] = dt;
        Session["ListofQuestion"] = listofquestion;
        ViewAllHistory.DataSource = dt;
        ViewAllHistory.DataBind();
        BindInsideGradeGrid();
        LegendMessage();
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}

protected void BindInsideGradeGrid()
{
    ArrayList listofquestion = (ArrayList)Session["ListofQuestion"];
    DataTable maintable = (DataTable)ViewState["HistoryGrid"];
    int indexgrid = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in maintable.Rows)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr2 = null;
        string userid = row["UserID"].ToString();
        ArrayList listofhistorydates = dbmanager.GetTotalHistoryDates(userid);

        for (int i = 0; i < listofhistorydates.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime toshortdate=((DateTime)listofhistorydates[i]);
            dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(toshortdate.ToShortDateString(), typeof(double)));
        }

        int index = 0;
        double result = 0.0;
        dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
        foreach (DateTime date in listofhistorydates)
        {
            foreach (Question qn in listofquestion)
            {
                result += dbmanager.GetAvgRating(userid, date, qn.QuestionID);
            }
            result = Math.Round((result / listofquestion.Count), 1);
            DateTime toshortdate = ((DateTime)listofhistorydates[index]);
            dr2[toshortdate.ToShortDateString()] = result;
            index++;
            result = 0.0;
        }
        dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);
        GridView gv = (GridView)ViewAllHistory.Rows[indexgrid].FindControl("GridView1");
        //gv.ControlStyle.Width = 500;
        gv.DataSource = dt2;
        gv.DataBind();
        indexgrid++;
    }
}
```

design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ViewAllHistory" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" BackColor="Black" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="1">
                            <RowStyle BackColor="White"/>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ViewBtn" runat="server" onclick="ViewBtn_Click">View</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" >
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Function" HeaderText="Function" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grade">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="ScrollPanel" style="width:760px" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal"> 
                                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" style="position:static" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="Black">
                                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                                            <RowStyle BackColor="White" Wrap="true"/>
                                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link shows a possible similar problem to yours. [How To exporting to Excel parent and nested GridView data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525537/how-to-exporting-to-excel-parent-and-nested-gridview-data)

You would need to iterate the rows of the grid, and see if any child grids exist.

Comment: hey one small favor here, do you know if i can remove the first column of the gridview? i tried gridView.Columns[0].Visible=false; but wont work.

Comment: You can set the column to visible=false in the HTML.

Comment: Private Sub dataGridView_RowDataBound( _
   ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs _
) Handles dataGridView.RowDataBound
   If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow OrElse _
      e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header OrElse _
      e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer _
   Then
      e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
   End If
End Sub

Comment: That is a vb.net method on how to not view a column, or you can just put it in HTML as I explained earlier <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" visible="false" HeaderText="User ID" />